# Duda sobre confección de base de datos y consultas

Tags: base-de-datos, select, join

tengo este archivo en Python para generar una base de datos en SQLITE3 con las siguientes tablas, alumnos, profesores, preceptores, barrio y localidad, al ir llenando una tabla por ej preceptores, luego barrio y localidad, me generan su correpodiente id en cada registro de la corespodiente tabla, pero al cambiar por ej a profesores, barrio y localidad los ids quedan registrados de tal modo que al querer hacer una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM preceptores 
JOIN barrio ON preceptores.id = barrio.id 
JOIN localidad ON barrio.id = localidad.id;
```

esta me da los ids de la tabla barrio y localidad que corresponde con ids de la tabla preceptores, es decir, como se guía por los ids toma el que sea igual al que le indico en la primer tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo cual es el problema pero no se como debo hacer las tablas para que esto no suceda o como debo hacer las consultas para corregir esto.
Pense en hacer una tabla personas y ahí poner una columna para discriminar, preceptores, profesores y alumnos... es lo que se me ocurrió, aunque preceptores y profesores tienen campos como usuario y clave los cuales alumnos no, en cuyo caso tendría que hacer otra tabla a parte con estos campos... le agradecería si me pueden orientar, saludos.

```
import sqlite3

conexion = sqlite3.connect('escuela.db')

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alumnos(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    nombre  TEXT,
    apellido TEXT,
    dni INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TEXT,
    telefono TEXT,
    mail TEXT,
    id_ba INTEGER,
    id_pre INTEGER,
    id_curso INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_curso) REFERENCES curso(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_pre) REFERENCES preceptores(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(id_ba) REFERENCES barrio(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profesores(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    nombre TEXT,
    apellido TEXT,
    dni INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TEXT,
    telefono TEXT,
    mail TEXT,
    id_ba INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_ba) REFERENCES barrio(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preceptores(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    usuario TEXT,
    clave TEXT,
    conf_clave TEXT,
    nombre TEXT,
    apellido TEXT,
    dni INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    fecha TEXT,
    telefono TEXT,
    mail TEXT, 
    id_ba INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_ba) REFERENCES barrio(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS barrio(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    calle TEXT,
    barrio TEXT,
    id_loc INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(id_loc) REFERENCES localidad(id));""")

conexion.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS localidad(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    localidad TEXT,
    CP INTEGER);""")
    
conexion.close()
```

Comment: Al parecer tu problema es SQL no de Python, te recomiendo enfoques tu pregunta en ese contexto. Y principalmente, que aclares cual es el problema, que lo leí 3 veces y no me queda claro